How to fix drivers after ubuntu-drivers install?
I have a freshly installed Kubuntu 24.04 on Lenovo Legion 5 laptop with Nvidia RTX 4060. I installed some apps and battery management and everything worked fine.
I followed this guide https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation to install nvidia drivers with sudo ubuntu-drivers install. After restarting, nvidia drivers were installed correctly but lot of other drivers seem to be missing. Touchpad is not working, input devices reports no touchpad found. Same for bluetooth and speakers/mic. Most importantly, it can't find ethernet and wifi devices. ip link doesn't show them. lspci -k shows them but without kernel driver line.
Is there any chance to fix at least the ethernet driver or do I have to install fresh OS?
